# Slack active extension for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, slack

I want to create a Chrome extension for Slack that is always active.
Even when we are not working on Slack, there are instances when we want to keep it active.
However, I can't seem to locate the extension for the aforementioned use.
I'd like to enlist the assistance of people with creative ideas.
I've already discovered a Chrome addon that wakes up the computer.

Comment: I think modern Chrome extensions automatically go to sleep to save on memory and processing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, the extension you wanted to make is just published. you can freely use it.

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/alwaysonline/ogafjbhfbmichdpppfebbcameeicchkg

There's tutorial on alwaysonline.io as well.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: You can signup for free and see the tutorial inside the app

Comment: that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: It's just hosted by Timurs Apps